# Wordpress site keeps redirecting to subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

sorry I am a complete newbie.

I've been building a website in wordpress that was located in a subdirectory /wp/wordpress

I was done with the website so I wanted it to start working using example.com path instead of example.com/wp/wordpress but i stumbled on some problems

I tried to copy htaccess and index.php files from wordpres directory to main directory and changing paths in index.php file, it worked, i could now access my website using example.com link but it still showed example.com/wp/wordpress path in the url section.

So i tried moving the whole website to root directory, to do that i did the following:

1.changed urls in wp-admin panel

2.moved all the files from /wp/wordpress to public_html main directory

3.accessed wp-admin panel again and using Update URLs plugin i updated the urls from example.com/wp/wordpress to example.com.

but the resoult wasnt what I expected, typing in the example.com url still redirected me to /wp/wordpress directory (path showing in url) which was now empty so it gave me an error.

How do I menage this situation, any ideas? Sorry if my post isnt clear, as I said I'm still a newbie

Comment: Did you update the htaccess file or update the permalinks setting? Did you see https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Moving_process?

Comment: you mean after moving files to the root directory? yes I tried updating it using codes found here but nothing seemed to work

but I havent updated permalinks, maybe that was the case, I'll try it right now

Comment: _"typing in the example.com url still redirected me to /wp/wordpress directory (path showing in url) which was now empty so it gave me an error"_ - make sure that's not just the browser cache tricking you - some browsers (especially Chrome, in my experience), cache redirects really heavily. Try a different browser, or append a random query string to make it a "new" URL.

Comment: wow you were right, it was chromes fault indeed thank you so much

Comment: @CBroe Thanks you, i was banging my head for past 1 hour trying to fix it. And i am so mad right now.

Answer (score 0):

This messed with me for two days. I'm pissed, the client is pissed. Only for me to find out that it was Chrome caching. So yes @CBroe is right. Try another browser and it will work.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35034852)